# maximum number of collinear points?

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry, online-resources

I know this is a very standard question widely popular in the Internet and the Mathworld.

I myself have solved the above problem is $N^2 \log N$ avoiding floating arithmetic.However, can anyone give me a good resource/detailed explanation of how it can be solved in $O(N^2)$ using point line duality concepts.

Sorry to create such a confusion regarding the statement.
The text would be:
"$N$ different points with integer coordinates are given in a plane. You are to write a program that finds the maximum number of collinear points (they all belong to the same line)."

You may also refer to [this site](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/CHASE/) which is the problem I have solved using a $N^2\log N$ approach.

Comment: For the sake of those readers not already familiar with the "standard question", perhaps you should include the question statement, either in-line or as a link to a fairly stable resource.

Comment: @Willie:  if not supplied, I would vote to close as not a real question

Comment: But how can you both 'have solved' the problem and not be able to write the precise statement for us?  We do not want 'an idea about the problem'.

Comment: @Ross and other -Im sorry for not having supplied the text earlier.

Comment: Related to Dan's response: the maximum number of colinear points from a set of $N$ given points is obviously $N$.  Let me suggest the rephrasing: "You are to find the largest number $M$ such that $M$ of the points from the original $N$ are colinear."  You probably find this implicit.

Answer (score 1):

By point-line duality, this is equivalent to the question 'given a configuration of $n$ lines in the plane, what is the maximum number of them which intersect at one point?'; since there are $O(n^2)$ pairwise intersection checks, it becomes a question of whether there's some bucketing/perfect hashing scheme that allows for finding a point in a dynamically-built list in $O(1)$ time.  While I don't know of any specific bucketing schemes applicable to this problem, AFAIK it's very common to have $O(1)$ or at least $O(\alpha(n))$ approaches for this sort of thing ($\alpha(n)$ being the inverse-Ackermann function).

Comment: I believe sweep-line type algorithms might work for the dual version. Of course, not sure :-) btw, if we were hashing, we could hash the line $y = mx + c \text{ as the pair } (m,c)$, do this $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ times and count the one with the max hits etc. Without resorting to point-line duality.

Comment: @moron That _almost_ works, but vertical lines cause you some issues.  You can use the $ax+by=c$ form and hash as a triplet but then you need to do a bit of fiddling to ensure that you identify _e.g._ $(a, b, c)$ with $(2a, 2b, 2c)$ - things get mildly tricky since you're dealing with a projective space. :-)

Comment: Also, of course, finding hashing schemes with guaranteed $O(1)$ performance is a remarkably non-trivial matter...

Comment: You could treat the verticals specially without too much trouble. Agree with the hash comment (I never claimed it was $\mathcal{O}(1)$):-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the two methods described in http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring03/cs226/assignments/lines.html .

To find 4 or more collinear points given $N$ points, the brute-force method has a time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(N^4)$, but a better method does it in $\mathcal{O}(N^2 \log N)$.

Answer (score -3):

The maximum number of collinear points among N points in a plane is N (i.e., if they happen to be collinear.)

Comment: They explanation in brackets is to help understand the collinear property.It isn't given that they are collinear already.

Comment: I might have answered the same, Ravi. Dan is pointing out that the usage of the word "maximum" is wrong.